# Replace string between two specific scripts in a file with shell script

Tags: bash, awk, sed, sh

I have a text file `info.txt` containing:

```
/* prog_dir=/path/to/some/directory; */
dir_1=/some/other/path/to/a/directory/first;
dir_2=/some/other/path/to/a/directory/secord;
```

Here, I want to replace the string present between these two pair of strings e.g. `dir_1=/some/other/path/to/a/directory/` and `;` AND `dir_2=/some/other/path/to/a/directory/` and `;` with `R03_0` for all lines `info.txt` file.

For each of the lines it should apply the replacement.

After the transformation, the `info.txt` file should be like:

```
/* prog_dir=/path/to/some/directory; */
dir_1=/some/other/path/to/a/directory/R03_0;
dir_2=/some/other/path/to/a/directory/R03_0;
```

Tried this one:

```
sed '/^dir_1=/some\/other\/path\/to\/a\/directory\//,/^;/R03_0' /path/to/the/text/file/info.txt
```

Also it would be better if we can pass the replacement script `R03_0` as a variable `$rel_ver` to the **sed/awk** command.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is the directory path same in all lines?

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following with sed:

```
pattern='\/some\/other\/path\/to\/a\/directory'
str='R03_0'
sed "s/${pattern}\/.*;/${pattern}\/${str};/g" info.txt
```

***Output:***

```
/* prog_dir=/path/to/some/directory; */
dir_1=/some/other/path/to/a/directory/R03_0;
dir_2=/some/other/path/to/a/directory/R03_0;
```

That will replace all `/some/other/path/to/a/directory/...;` to your desired pattern, that is `/some/other/path/to/a/directory/R03_0;`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use group capture to achieve this:

```
sed -re 's#^(/some/other/path/to/a/directory/).*;#\1R03_0;#g' info.txt
```

This will 'save' the pattern that matches in the braces, and drop it back in at `\1`

Answer (score 0):

As all lines are ending with a `;`:

```
str='R03_3';
sed -e "s/\(^.*\/\).*;$/\1${str};/" info.txt
```

- `\(^.*\/\)` - capture group matching beginning of line, any character and a forward slash
- `.+;$` - at least one character followed by `;` at the end of line
- `\1${str};` - replaces by the capture group and the text defined in variable `str`

**Note** this will not change the file, redirect the output or use `-i` option to replace inplace.